# MariaDB settings in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mariadb

A while back I created an instance of mariadb inside a docker container on a machine running Ubuntu. I've since learned that I'll need to update some settings to keep things running smoothly, but when I created the image, I did not specify any .cnf volumes. How do I update/create a .cnf file for this image? I'm a complete newb when it comes to docker, so please spoon-feed me.

I've tried accessing the file from within the image, but there are no text editors.

Answer (score 0):

The defaults of MariaDB work pretty much out of the box (container) for small instances. You should only need to change setting when problems occur.

If you have spare memory you can increase your [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size%5D).

With the mariadb container, you don't need to edit the .cnf files, you can just add a few options on the command line per [the docs (that you should defiantly read)](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/).

Recommend using the defaults for a while, and if you encounter problems, include a new question on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) that includes `show global status` output and specifics on the queries that are slow (`show create table TBLNAME` / `explain QUERY`).